# Issue in summing the value using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query I have 2 tables `locationproductmap` and `productsourceproductmap`. My aim is to multiply the quantifier from the `productsourceproductmap` table with `CurrentUnitPrice` from the `locationproductmap` table, and then sum it. But my actual result is displaying incorrect result.

Please help me to do this.

Actual result is 45.

**productsourceproductmap**

```
Productid  | Quantifier| locationId
-----------------------------------
1402              1            1
1403              1            1
1404              1            1
```

**locationproductmap**

```
ProductId    | Locationid |CurrentUnit Price
--------------------------------------------
1402              1            5
1403              1            5
1404              1            5
```

**Query**

```
(Select  
     SUM(LPM.CurrentUnitPrice * PSPM.Quatifier) 
 From 
     LocationProductMap LPM 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ProductSourceProductMap PSPM ON PSPM.ProductID IN (1402, 1404, 1403)  
 WHERE 
     LPM.ProductID IN (1402, 1404, 1403) 
     AND LPM.LocationID = 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select  SUM(LPM.CurrentUnitPrice * PSPM.Quatifier) 
From LocationProductMap LPM 
LEFT Join ProductSourceProductMap PSPM ON PSPM.ProductID = LPM.ProductID 
WHERE LPM.LocationID = 1
AND LPM.ProductID IN (1402,1404,1403)
```

When joining specify the link of the tables in the `ON` condition. If you want to filter the data then add that to your `where` clause.

Comment: `ProductID IN (1402,1404,1403)`

Comment: Can you be more specific?